# Regular Expressions - picking off a number before unit specifier in sentence

Tags: java, regex, string

I have sentences that represent directions, and I need to pick off the distance specified for these directions - just the number. Here are examples:

```
"Head northwest on Lincoln St toward Warbuton Ave 0.1 mi" //0.1
"Head northwest on Middlefield Rd toward Embarcadero Rd 95 ft" //95
"Make a U-turn at Warbuton Ave 0.3 mi" //0.3
"Take the first right onto Embarcadero Rd 12.43 mi" //12.43
```

The possible unit specifiers are "ft" and "mi". The number itself is in general a decimal. What would be the regex to pick out these numbers? There may be other numbers in the string, but generally not of the form `xy.zw mi`.

I'm starting with `\d*\.\d* mi` though I'd like to be able to check for `ft` in the same expression if possible. Also, I realize that for non-decimal numbers this doesn't work... need to make the decimal and trailing digits optional I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern you should use is:

```
\d++(?:\.\d++)?(?=\s*+(?:mi|ft))
```

Lets go through it:

- `\d++` regex digits group matches one or more times, possesively
- `(?:\.\d++)?` a dot followed by the above in an optional non-capturing group (so 10 would be matched at well as 10.11
- `(?=\s*+(?:mi|ft))` a lookahead assertion for any amount of whitespace followed by `mi` or `ft`

Here is an example in Java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    final String[] in = {"Head northwest on Lincoln St toward Warbuton Ave 0.1 mi",
        "Head northwest on Middlefield Rd toward Embarcadero Rd 95 ft",
        "Make a U-turn at Warbuton Ave 0.3 mi",
        "Take the first right onto Embarcadero Rd 12.43 mi"};
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]++(?:\\.[0-9]++)?(?=\\s++(?:mi|ft))", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    for (final String s : in) {
        final Matcher m = pattern.matcher(s);
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group());
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> 0.1
>   95
>   0.3
>   12.43

Note the double escapes in the Java code. I have also added the `CASE_INSENSITIVE` flag, this is to that we match all permutations of, for example, `ft` `Ft` `FT` etc.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following regular expression..

```
(\d+(.\d+)?) (mi|ft)
```

Here's an example.. [ideone](http://ideone.com/bKTwpQ)

**EDIT**
An even better regex, as suggested by **Ingo** in the comment, would be..

```
(\d+(.\d+)?)\s*(mi|ft)\b
```

Comment: To make it more defensive, consider to replace the space with `\s*`. Furthermore, I'd add a word break `\b` at the end so that a substring like "50 minutes" will **not** be matched.

Comment: @Ingo- Updated, and +1 to you

Answer (score 2):

Example of matching the floating point number could be found at [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html).

`ft` or `mi` is written as `(ft|mi)`.

Concatenation of those regexes is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,2})?(?=\s(ft|mi))
```

Here's a [working example](http://regexr.com?35aoa)

Converting this regex to a working Java regex is left as an exercise.

Comment: And what if something is 100 ft away?

Comment: The requirement of the OP clearly states the format `xy.zw ft or mi`.

Comment: I think that's saying that the number is floating point not that it is always two digits.

Comment: I think if that was the case, he would mention that it MAY be a floating point number, but the fact that he explicitly mentioned the format is confusing.